# For loop producing IndexOutOfRange error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I keep getting the following error and unsure has to how fix it. As a fairly new user to VB.NET, I think it is saying that there are no rows at that position? To compensate for this, I included an If statement to check the row count, but it is still producing this error. In fact, the messagebox is not firing at all. Can someone please advise as to how I can correct this error. Thanks

Link where code obtained: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305271/en-us

> There is no row at position 1.

```
Private Sub loadpages()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim startRec As Integer
    Dim endRec As Integer
    Dim dtTemp As DataTable
    'Dim dr As DataRow

    'Duplicate or clone the source table to create the temporary table.
    dtTemp = dtSource.Clone

    If currentPage = PageCount Then
        endRec = maxRec
    Else
        endRec = pageSize * currentPage
    End If

    startRec = recNo

    'Copy the rows from the source table to fill the temporary table.
    If dtSource.Rows.Count <> 0 Then

        For i = startRec To endRec - 1
            dtTemp.ImportRow(dtSource.Rows(i)) <--- ERROR HERE
            recNo = recNo + 1
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(dtSource.Rows.Count.ToString())
    End If
    frmMain.DGV.DataSource = dtTemp
    DisplayPageInfo()
    'fillPostings()
End Sub
```

combobox sub to change pagesize

```
Sub cmbpage()

        'Set the start and max records. 
        pageSize = CInt(frmMain.cmbPageSize.Text)
        maxRec = dtSource.Rows.Count
        PageCount = maxRec \ pageSize
        MessageBox.Show(CStr(maxRec))
        ' Adjust the page number if the last page contains a partial page.
        If (maxRec Mod pageSize) > 0 Then
            PageCount = PageCount + 1
        End If

        'Initial seeings
        currentPage = 1
        recNo = 0

        ' Display the content of the current page.

        UDGfillPostings()
        loadpages()

    End Sub
```

Comment: what's the value `startRec` and `endRec`?

Comment: Try For i = 0 To dtSource.Rows.Count - 1 Then ... instead and see if that works.

Comment: Have you tried MessageBox.Show(dtSource.Rows.Count.ToString()) ?

Comment: Vikram it errors before it gets to the messagebox so it is never fired. Thanks

Comment: @sachin The startRec values are whatever value the user chooses from a drop down. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 So what's the relation between `startRec` value and the records that should be imported into temp table

Comment: @Sachin Not quite sure I understand your answer. I have posted the whole sub as this may make things clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this looping.

```
For i = 0 To dtSource.Rows.Count-1
```

If you just want to copy one DataTable to another then you can just use [DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method.

```
 Dim dtTemp As DataTable
 dtTemp = dtSource.Copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

you have assigned `startRec` to 1,so it is throwing error when `dtSource.Rows(1)`,as there is only one element in the array

you can rectify this by using `dtSource.Rows(i-1)`

Comment: dtTemp.ImportRow(dtSource.Rows(i - 1)) still produces error. Thanks